# Looking for a COM Input Plugin allowing SQL SERVER as an Input Format

Tags: sql, logparser

Is anyone aware of any links/urls that document how to write a Windows Script Component COM that will allow SQL Server as a custom Input Format for LogParser 2.2?

Thanks for sharing this and any other insight into this.

Answer (score 2):

Logparser Lizard GUI will support SQL as an input source.